# Intellij on M1 Mac: Flutter Inspector stuck on details of first selected widget

Tags: flutter

I'm using the latest version of Flutter Inspector in IntelliJ Ultimate on my M1 Mac. I use it to check an application that runs in an iOS Simulator.

My problem: After I select a widget from the tree, the "Details Tree" tab is then stuck with that widget. I can't see details of other widgets (that are not below this widget), no matter which one I select. Here's a [video demonstrating the issue](https://www.screencast.com/t/1WjzQVvnTG).

I tried to left-click on widgets in the tree, right-click, double-click. I use the "Select Widget Mode" button to select a widget directly in my app. But nothing updates the "Details Tree". What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my configuration:

- macOS 12.2.1 on M1 Max
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 Ultimate, Build #IU-213.6777.52 (January 28, 2022)
- IntelliJ Runtime: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains 11.0.13+7-b1751.25 aarch64
- IntelliJ Dart plugin: 213.5744.122
- IntelliJ Flutter plugin: 64.1.4
- Flutter runtime in app: 2.10.2 (stable channel)

Comment: Have you opened up an issue on their git repo ?

Comment: Nope. I can't believe something so fundamental is broken.

Comment: Now I opened [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3732).